# A question about $2$-transitive group definition

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, definition, group-actions

Given a group $G$ acting on a set $X$ with $|X| \ge 2$, we say that the action of $G$ on $X$ is 2-transitive iff for any $y_1,y_2 \in X$ with $y_1 \neq y_2$ and $x_1,x_2 \in X$ with $x_1 \neq x_2$ there is $g \in G$ such that $g \cdot x_1 = y_1$ and $g \cdot x_2 = y_2$

The thing that is not too clear from this definition is that I could simply take $x_1 = y_1$ and $x_2 = y_2$ and then $g = \{e\}$ to make this always hold. Is maybe implied in the definition that we should choose a non-trivial $g \in G$?

Comment: Note that the definition says it has to hold for all $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$ such that $x_1\ne x_2$ and $y_1\ne y_2$. So you can't just choose specific elements from $X$.

Comment: right, many thanks

Comment: It might be useful to note that the definition is equivalent to the following one, which is apparently more restrictive. $G$ is $2$-transitive on $X$ iff there exist $x_{1}, x_{2} \in X$, with $x_{1} \ne x_{2}$, such that for all $y_1,y_2 \in X$ with $y_1 \neq y_2$  there is $g \in G$ such that $g \cdot x_1 = y_1$ and $g \cdot x_2 = y_2$.

Comment: I don't know where you got that definition from, but  the word "any" is ambiguous. You should replace "for any" with "for all" in the definition. That might be the source of your confusion.